# How can i bring an image from an api and show it in my app?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the api:

```
"page": 1,
    "results": [
        {
            "original_language": "en",
            "original_title": "Mortal Kombat",
            "popularity": 2309.097,
            "poster_path": "/nkayOAUBUu4mMvyNf9iHSUiPjF1.jpg",
}
```

This is the way I'm trying to get the image from it and saving it in a variable:

````
class MostPopular {
  MostPopular({
    this.image0,})
   
    final String image0;

  factory MostPopular.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    final String image =
        (json["results"] as List).map((j) => j["poster_path"]).toList()[0];

return MostPopular(
      image0: image,)
 }
}```

And when i run the app, it shows `/nkayOAUBUu4mMvyNf9iHSUiPjF1.jpg`  and not the image. I tried changing the `String` but it still doesn't work and I'm not sure if thats the problem.
````

Comment: "/nkayOAUBUu4mMvyNf9iHSUiPjF1.jpg" is just the image path. You also need the domain, something like `https://example.com/images/nkayOAUBUu4mMvyNf9iHSUiPjF1`. Where are you fetching your data from ?

Comment: i'm getting the data from here: https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=0e685fd77fb3d76874a3ac26e0db8a4b&language=en-US&page=1

Comment: and this is what themoviedb says in their page to set an image: https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/kqjL17yufvn9OVLyXYpvtyrFfak.jpg

Comment: but i don't know how to put it in flutter

Comment: let me check their api.

Comment: I have posted an answer, check out if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are actually getting from the api is just the image `path`.

However you must still append the actual base url of their domain.

From their documention,

> Here's what a full image URL looks like if the poster_path of /kqjL17yufvn9OVLyXYpvtyrFfak.jpg was returned for a movie, and you were looking for the w500 size:
> https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/kqjL17yufvn9OVLyXYpvtyrFfak.jpg

So, change your function to this,

```
return MostPopular(image0: 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${image}')
```

and when you want to use it, you can probably use it like this,

```
Image.network(mostPopular.image0); // where mostPopular is an instance of MostPopular
```

Comment: But I have to ask, why are you using `.toList()[0]`, dont you want all the images ? Or are you fetching the list and taking only first since its the most popular one ?

Comment: yes, i have 9 more variables for 9 more images but i just showed you only one because stack overflow didn't let me put it all, the code was so long, that's why i use the .toList()[] to get the 10 images. Thank you so much for your answer and your help!!!!

Comment: Understood. Is your issue solved ? Please consider accepting the answer or else tell me if you want some more things in the answer :)

Comment: yes, my issue has been solved, thank you so much for your answer and help!!!

Comment: Yes sure!! but how can i do that? i'm new at this just tell me how to accept it and i'll do it.

Comment: `To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.` This is from the docs.

Comment: okay i think i already did it, it says 'Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.' is that okay to set it as accepted?

Comment: Hi, check this out. This might help you in your journey through Stack overflow - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251399/10780861